# .Net hanging on HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync()

Tags: .net, wpf, httpclient

I have a WPF application (.Net Framework 4.8) which calls a RESTful web api to retrieve some data from a database (Web Api written in ASP .Net Core 2.2)

Code:

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task<List<DataPacket>> GetNewDataAsync()
        {
            string uri = $"{apiUrl}/readings";

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<DataPacket> data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<DataPacket>>();
                return data;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

When I execute this program, it hangs on the following line:

```
List<DataPacket> data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<DataPacket>>();
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have a `Wait` or `Result` further up your callstack. [That will cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I took your advice, and realized the problem was that I didn't have await when calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't have await when calling this function.

Comment: Please post how you resolved completely which will relevant for future users